# Vagrant: Log into an user account without ssh private keys

Tags: ssh, vagrant

I created another user in a vagrant machine, and I would like to log into it by default. I wanted to know if there is a way of logging into it with it's password without having to put the password in plain-text Vagrantfile.

Comment: you can configure `ssh.username` and vagrant will prompt for its password

Comment: @FrédéricHenri but it still tries to log into automatically after I do an vagrant up with ssh private keys. It's just that I didn't want to do an Ctrl+c right after I started the machine to log in with vagrant ssh